# Names Argument Plotly Barplot

Tags: r, label, shiny, bar-chart, plotly

So I am using Plotly in Shiny to create a bar chart. However the x labels are not unique for example (Dog twice):

Let the df be:

```
x     y
1     Dog
2     Cat
3     Dog
3     Ant
4     Bee
```

I would like all the rows to be plotted but this won't work because of the repeated variable Dog in the x column:

```
p = plot_ly(df, x = df[,2],  y = df[,1], type = "bar", marker = list(color = toRGB("blue")))
p
```

So I am thinking of getting past this doing something like:
I am able to plot all 5 rows by removing the x argument. Then I want to be able to modify these names separately to fill in the x column variables.

```
p = plot_ly(df,  y = x, type = "bar", marker = list(color = toRGB("blue")))
p
```

How do you manually change the x labels in plotly barplot?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Straightforward official method:**

Use the `tickmode`, `tickvals`, and `ticktext` arguments in `layout` for `xaxis`:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(df, y = x, type = "bar", 
        marker = list(color = toRGB("blue"))) %>% 
         layout(xaxis = list(tickmode = "array",
                             tickvals = 0:4,
                             ticktext = c("Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Ant", "Bee")))
```

I am not sure how well would `y = x` in the above command generalize in other kinds of plots. Hence, I recommend this approach:

```
# change the y labels (I assigned "a", "b" etc.) 
df$y <- letters[1:nrow(df)]


df %>% plot_ly(x = y,  y = x, type = "bar", 
               marker = list(color = toRGB("blue"))) %>% 
               layout(xaxis = list(tickmode = "array",
                                   tickvals = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                                   ticktext = c("Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Ant", "Bee")))
```

**Short hack:**

Just add a whitespace at the end of second occurrence of dog:

```
df$y <- as.character(df$y)
df[3,2] <- "Dog "
```

You can then use your first plot command:

```
plot_ly(df, x = df[,2],  y = df[,1], type = "bar", marker = list(color = toRGB("blue")))
```

I checked plots for both the approaches, and they look the same. 
Obviously, your real application might not be this simple and the hack probably won't be feasible.

Plus, you can always use `ggplot2` and then make your plots interactive with `plotly::ggplotly`

Comment: Brilliant, using the first way and it works well. Thank you very much.